# Netlogo, Moving Turtle along links

Tags: netlogo

I am doing model where I want my agents to move along links between nodes. The idea is that all turtles move a constant distance after each tick. (Note I dont want them jump from one node to the another, also lets assume that its not possible to make the nodes at a constant distances, because I am trying to implement it on a gis model where of course the vertices are not at constant distances)

For this model there are two type of agents butterflies and collectors. Each of the agents placed on nodes which are linked to each other. The collectors find the closest butterfly to them using in-radius and then finds the path using nw: turtles-on-weight-path function. So for example lets suppose collector-02 has located butterfly-19. The path is [node-2 node-5 node-1 node-9]. I want the collector to travel to these nodes to get to the butterfly but instead of jumping to each node. He has to travel a distance of 0.01 netlogo units on the link from node-2 to node-5 and eventually node-9 where the butterfly is located.
The function follow-path is incomplete and it where i getting into trouble.
ANy ideas how to solve this problem. Thanks

```
extensions [nw]
globals [current-loc-global butterfly-location link-distance]

breed [nodes node]
breed [collectors collector]
breed [butterflys butterfly]

links-own [dist]
nodes-own [consist-butterfly linked-to]
collectors-own [ distance-from-location current-loc new-location targeted- 
butterfly initial-node next-node current-node previous-node
node-butterfly-at commute-path route-length next-pos]
butterflys-own [ initial-node-collectors targeted? node-butterfly-on]

to setup
  clear-all

  ;creating nodes
  create-nodes 60[
    set color blue
    set shape "circle"
    set consist-butterfly nobody
  ]
  ask nodes [create-link-with one-of other nodes]


  repeat 500[layout]
  ask nodes [setxy 0.95 * xcor * 0.95 ycor]

 create-butterflys number-of-butterflys[
    set node-butterfly-on one-of nodes
    set shape "butterfly"
    move-to node-butterfly-on
    set initial-node-collectors current-loc-global
    set targeted? false
  ]

  ask nodes [
    set consist-butterfly min-one-of butterflys in-radius 0.0001 [distance 
myself]
  ]


  create-collectors number-of-collectors[
    set current-loc one-of nodes with [consist-butterfly = nobody]
    set color red
    set targeted-butterfly nobody
    move-to current-loc
  ]

  ask collectors[
  set current-loc-global  current-loc
  ]

  ask links [
    let end-point-1 end1
    let end-point-2 end2
    set link-distance 0
    ask end1[set linked-to end-point-2
      set link-distance distance end-point-2
    ]
    set dist link-distance
    ask end2[
      set linked-to end-point-1
    ]
  ]

  reset-ticks
end

to layout
  layout-spring nodes links 0.5 1 1
end

to go
  find-agents
  find-path
  follow-path 
end

to find-agents
  ask collectors [
    if targeted-butterfly = nobody[set targeted-butterfly min-one-of 
    butterflys in-radius 10 with [not targeted?] [distance myself]]
    if targeted-butterfly != nobody [ask targeted-butterfly [set targeted? 
    true]]
  ]

  ask collectors with [targeted-butterfly != nobody][

    ask targeted-butterfly [set butterfly-location node-butterfly-on]
    set node-butterfly-at butterfly-location
  ]
end

to find-path
  ask collectors with [targeted-butterfly != nobody ][

    set initial-node min-one-of nodes in-radius 0.0001 [distance myself]
    let end-location node-butterfly-at

    let path []
    ask initial-node [set path nw:turtles-on-weighted-path-to end-location 
    dist]
    set commute-path path

    set route-length length commute-path

    set current-node initial-node
    set previous-node current-node
    set next-node current-node
  ]
end

to follow-path
  ask collectors with [targeted-butterfly != nobody][
  set distance-from-location distance current-node
    ifelse 0.09 < distance-from-location
    [jump 0.09]
    [move-to current-node
     set current-node next-node
      face next-node]
```

]

end

Answer (score 1):

Managed to sort it out. Need to change the follow-path function as follows:

```
to follow-path
 ask collectors with [targeted-butterfly != nobody][
  set distance-from-location distance current-node

  set next-pos ((position(current-node) commute-path) + 1)
  if next-pos < route-length [set next-node item(next-pos) commute-path]

    ifelse 0.09 < distance-from-location
    [jump 0.09]
    [move-to current-node
     set current-node next-node
      face next-node]
  ]

end
```